# why the controller and HTML are not linked?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ng-controller

I have the following code - which displays the login page with validation. But looks like something is wrong and all validation texts are always shown. Whats wrong. How can I add it as separate controller module?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="angularCordova01App">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <!--<div class="header">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">angularCordovaTickrv01</a>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a ng-href="#/about">About</a></li>
              <li><a ng-href="#/">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>-->

    <header class="header">
        <h4> Welcome</h4>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
      <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer footertxt">
      <div class="container">
        <p>@Copyright </p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
    <!-- <script>
       !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
       (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
       r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
       }(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>-->
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/cordova.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

main.html:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <div class="row">  

      <div class="col-xs-12">
          <!-- FORM ============ -->

          <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>

              <!-- USERNAME -->
              <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : userForm.username.$invalid && !userForm.username.$pristine }">
                  <label>Username</label>
                  <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8">
                  <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Username is too short.</p>
                  <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Username is too long.</p>
              </div>

              <!-- Password -->
              <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.pwd.$invalid && !userForm.pwd.$pristine }">
                  <label>Password</label>
                  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.pwd">
                  <p ng-show="userForm.pwd.$invalid && !userForm.pwd.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid Password.</p>
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>

          </form>

      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

MainCtrl:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name angularCordova01App.controller:MainCtrl
 * @description
 * # MainCtrl
 * Controller of the angularCordovaTickrv01App
 */
angular.module('angularCordova01App')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, cordova) {
    console.log("Hello...")
    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
    cordova.ready.then(function () {
        alert('Cordova is ready');
    });

    // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
    $scope.submitForm = function() {

        // check to make sure the form is completely valid
        if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
            alert('our form is amazing');
            console.log("For submitted..")
        }

    };
});
```

Also, I get the following error:

```css
ReferenceError: $q is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/scripts/services/cordova.js:15:13)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4625:19)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4464:37)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4625:19)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4424:37
    at getService (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4571:39)
    at injectionArgs (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4595:58)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4637:18)
    at $controller (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10042:28)
    at link (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:1007:26) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They're shown because they're invalid that's all this is the expected behaviour this is why usually error messages are wrapped like this :

```
<div ng-if="userForm.username.$dirty || userForm.username.$touched">
    <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Username is too short.</p>
    <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Username is too long.</p>
 </div>
```

$dirty : if the value of the fields has been changed. 
$touched : if the user click in the field and get out of it, even if not changing the value.